# Testing Ember.Logger.error assertions

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I'm using Ember.Logger.error:

```
if (isInvalid) {
  Ember.Logger.error('this is invalid');
}
```

I want to test it in qunit:

```
assert.throws(() => myFunction(), /this is invalid/, 'error was thrown');
```

But `assert.throws` doesn't catch the error. It does if I replace `Ember.Logger.error` with a simple `throw` statement, but surely there's a way to test for logged Ember errors. Anyone know the way?

UPDATE:

I made a little addon that adds this ability to QUnit. You can get it [here](https://github.com/null-null-null/ember-logger-test).

Comment: What kind of test is it? Is it component, controller, helper unit-test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I've done a research how it's done in Ember and I've seen what's the practice to test it:

- [ember.js/packages/ember/tests/helpers/link_to_test.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/cb938608adff9343c0071177ff45aad6b6f41125/packages/ember/tests/helpers/link_to_test.js#L1004)
- [ember.js/packages/ember/tests/routing/basic_test.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/cb938608adff9343c0071177ff45aad6b6f41125/packages/ember/tests/routing/basic_test.js#L91)

Here's example test function you could use to test calling `Ember.Logger.error` in helper unit test:

```
/* global Ember */

import { demo } from '../../../helpers/demo';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('Unit | Helper | demo');

test('catching log', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1); // define how many assertions we expect

  const oldError = Ember.Logger.error; // store original error function in variable

  Ember.Logger.error = function(message) { // monkey patch with our custom function
    assert.equal(message, 'this is invalid', 'error was thrown'); // our assertion
  };

  demo(); // actually call function

  Ember.Logger.error = oldError; // restore original error function
});
```

Comment: This works great! It's a bit verbose, so I decided to encapsulate it in a custom qunit assertion. Next step is to make a little addon that will give any app access to the new qunit assertion, `logs`. Also, while looking for the testing equivalent of an initializer, I came across this [issue](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/issues/140). Thanks for being involved!

Comment: The world is small. :D

Comment: Actually, is there an equivalent to an initializer in ember qunit tests? As far as I can tell, there isn't. At least for unit tests that don't run `App.injectTestHelpers()`.

Comment: I am not enough comfortable and competent to answer that question.

Comment: Was able to get this working by using the `test-body-footer` content tag. If you're interested, you'll find the addon [here](https://github.com/null-null-null/ember-logger-test).